# Alexa site rank API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Today I was working on Alexa API to get sites popularity rank using this code:

```
import urllib.request, sys, re

site = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/'
xml = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=%s'%site).read()
try: rank = int(re.search(r'<POPULARITY[^>]*TEXT="(\d+)"', xml).groups()[0])
except: rank = -1
print('Your rank for %s is %d!\n' % (site, rank))
```

It was working perfectly, but suddenly it stopped!, I checked the API link manually:

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
```

and it just returns a word "Okay" rather than a XML string .. What is the problem ?!

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work since 10th of May. Haven't found a new working URL for that. Only this html alternative: https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Comment: Here is a smaller html alternative from alexa toolbar: https://www.alexa.com/minisiteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 6):

This might be what you are looking for

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url='wikipedia.com'
rank_str =BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.alexa.com/minisiteinfo/" +url),'html.parser').table.a.get_text()
rank_int=int(rank_str.replace(',',''))
print(rank_int)
```

Comment: This API is retired as of today. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

That okey means that the IP you are running the script from has been blacklisted by alexa.

If you run it from a different IP it will work. Having said that I have no idea what rate / limit will cause IPs to be blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

That link seems to work fine for me when I tried it in Chrome and in Postman. Are you saying that the regex is returning "Okay"?

Also the response from that link is not in JSON, it is XML. Instead of using a regex to parse XML I would suggest that you use the [XML module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Edit: I just tried you code and it worked, although I needed to convert the response to string (it came in as a byte-like object) before passing it into the regex.

Comment: it doesn't return anything for me, just Okay word !

Comment: The URL or the regex? Which is returning "Okay"?

Comment: the URL .. just a blank page with okay word

Comment: I confirm that the problem began on the 10th of May. It just returns "Okay". Perhaps I need to use the official API - even if you make over 1000 requests, it's very cheap anyway.

Comment: http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=
is working in browsers, but returns "Okey" if you requested it from scripts

Answer (score 0):

Alexa rank has moved to new place and now is offered through paid API - https://awis.alexa.com/developer-guide. Said that, it is not expensive -https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07Q71HJ3H